# Why does changing my "STATIC_URL" setting alter whether my Django application works?

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

In settings.py, if I specify `STATIC_URL = 'http://68.164.125.221/'`, then clients can visit my web page. However, no CSS and other static files load.

On the other hand, if I specify `STATIC_URL = '/'`, then visiting the home page of my application produces this error.

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://68.164.125.221/
Directory indexes are not allowed here.
You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file.
```

Interestingly, my static files now load (http://68.164.125.221/main.css loads for instance) despite the home page of my app displaying this error.

Why does changing my "STATIC_URL" setting toggle whether my home page loads or my static files load? I am using the staticfiles app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want `STATIC_URL = '/static/'`[1]; when you set it to `/` Django is trying to serve up `/blah/` as a static file rather than pushing it through to your Django app.

The actual error you're getting, `Directory indexes are not allowed here.`, refers to the fact that the static file folders aren't listed out - you must access a specific file for it to be served up.

[1] Or /media/, or /files/, or whatever... just not '/'.

Comment: Thanks, specifying `STATIC_URL = '/static/'` works. What do you mean though by Django is trying to serve up '/blah/' as as static file? You mean all of my URL mapping is being treated as static files?

Comment: Yes, by setting `STATIC_URL='/'` Django is ignoring your URL mapping and trying to serve everything as static files. (Assuming you're using the built-in dev server)